# Catching 'division by zero' in a function with array parameters

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, where-clause

I pass an array of values as arguments to a function. This function divides somewhere by the values given as arguments. I want to bypass the calculation for zero-value values so that I don't have to divide by zero.

```
import numpy as np

def test(t):
    e = np.where(t==0,0,10/t)
    return e

i = np.arange(0, 5, 1)
print('in: ',i)

o = test(i)
print('out:',o)
```

Output is

```
in:  [0 1 2 3 4]
out: [ 0.         10.          5.          3.33333333  2.5       ]

<ipython-input-50-321938d419be>:4: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  e = np.where(t==0,0,10/t)
```

I thought np.where would be the appropriate function for this, but unfortunately I always get a runtime warning 'divide by zero'. So, it does the right thing, but the warning is annoying. I could of course suppress the warning, but I wonder if there is a cleaner solution to the problem?

Comment: use exception handling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.divide(10, t, where=t!=0)`:

```
import numpy as np

def test(t):
    e = np.divide(10, i, where=i!=0)
    return e

i = np.arange(0, 5, 1)
print('in: ',i)

o = test(i)
print('out:',o)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can test if the divisor is zero, like you do but consider testing if it is equal to a floating point zero `0.0` , or otherwise provide floating point arguments.

Change `test`

```
def test(t):
    e = np.where(t==0.0,0,10.0/t) # Note : t == 0.0 (a float comparison)
    return e
```

And/or use floating point arguments:

```
i = np.arange(0., 5., 1.)
```

Will give you the result with out an exception too.

Comment: If you use `where` you will necessarily have the error, `where` does not execute one or the other, it takes both inputs and chooses based on the condition. The error happens **before** where is even called

Comment: @mozway, worked for me Python 3.10, NumPy 1.22.4

Comment: The warning persists in my case.

Comment: @scinopode - Hmm, I'll try on a different Python version. I reproduced your warning with your original code.